# Jasper Report and Netbeans 7.2

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I'm having trouble to load a report through a button.This is my code.When I click the button it shows the down image error.

```
try {
 InputStream in =
 getClass().getResourceAsStream("C:/Users/RaMiNdU/Documents/NetBeansProjects/TimeTable
 Generator/src/timetable/generator/sem1.jrxml");
 JasperDesign jasperDesign = JRXmlLoader.load(in);
 Map<String, Object> param = new HashMap<>();
 JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(jasperDesign);
 JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, param );
 JasperViewer.viewReport(jasperPrint, false);
 } catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
 }
```

[image: This is the error message which is displaying ..when I click the button]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add commons-digester.jar to your classpath and you should be through

Comment: Still it shows an error -Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/collections/ArrayStack
at org.apache.commons.digester.Digester.<init>(Digester.java:138)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlDigester.<init>(JRXmlDigester.java:62)at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlDigesterFactory.createDigester(JRXmlDigesterFactory.java:988)
 at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader.load(JRXmlLoader.java:203)

Comment: add commons-collection.jar as well

Comment: yeah ..it works ..now no errors ... but this "run:
java.net.MalformedURLException" and not giving the report also ..

Comment: The URL for local file needs to start with file:

Answer (score 0):

- commons-digester is not available in the Classpath.
- Any start-up script is overriding Classpath environment variable.
- Check for java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError in your log file. NoClassDefFoundError due 
  to failure of static initialization is quite common.
- Your class may not be visible while using multiple class loaders.